# An error occurred while executing the query: tuple index out of range

Tags: sqlite

The meaning of the application is as follows. Sql queries are stored in the database, the user selects the database with a checkbox, selects the application to which the database belongs with a drop-down list and selects the sql query that he wants to execute in the selected database.
class UserApplication(tk.Tk):
def **init**(self):
super().**init**()

```
    self.title("User App")
    self.geometry("500x500")  # Устанавливаем размеры окна

    # Получаем размеры экрана
    screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight()

    # Вычисляем координаты для размещения окна по центру
    x = (screen_width - 500) // 2  # 500 - ширина окна
    y = (screen_height - 500) // 2  # 500 - высота окна

    # Устанавливаем координаты окна
    self.geometry(f"500x500+{x}+{y}")

    self.selected_databases = []  # Инициализируем список для хранения выбранных баз данных

    self.create_menu()
    # Создаем интерфейс пользователя
    self.create_user_interface()

def create_menu(self):
    # Создаем вертикальное меню
    menu_bar = tk.Menu(self)

    # Добавляем пункты в меню
    menu = tk.Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)
    menu.add_command(label="Выполнить", command=self.open_execute_window)

    sub_menu = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
    menu.add_command(label="Запросы", command=self.open_new_window)

    menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Первый", menu=menu)

    # Добавляем пункт "О приложении"
    menu_bar.add_command(label="О приложении", command=self.show_about_window)

    # Устанавливаем меню как основное меню окна
    self.config(menu=menu_bar)

def create_user_interface(self):
    label = ttk.Label(self, text="Я не знаю что тут должно быть", font=("Arial", 14))
    label.pack(pady=200)

def open_new_window(self):
    # Создаем новое окно с вкладками
    new_window = tk.Toplevel(self)
    new_window.title("Внесение данных")

    # Получаем размеры экрана
    screen_width = new_window.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = new_window.winfo_screenheight()

    # Вычисляем координаты для размещения окна по центру
    x = (screen_width - 600) // 2  # 600 - ширина окна
    y = (screen_height - 400) // 2  # 400 - высота окна

    # Устанавливаем координаты окна
    new_window.geometry(f"600x400+{x}+{y}")

    tab_control = ttk.Notebook(new_window)

    # Получаем все названия программ из базы данных
    program_names = self.get_program_names()

    # Создаем вкладки и заполняем их данными
    for program_name in program_names:
        # Проверяем, есть ли уже вкладка с таким названием
        existing_tabs = tab_control.tabs()
        if program_name not in existing_tabs:
            tab = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
            tab_control.add(tab, text=program_name)
            self.create_fields(tab, program_name)  # Передаем имя вкладки
        else:
            messagebox.showwarning("Предупреждение", f"Вкладка с названием '{program_name}' уже существует.")

    tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

def get_program_names(self):
    try:
        connection = sqlite3.connect('first.db')
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        # Получаем все названия программ из таблицы "Название программ"
        cursor.execute("SELECT Название FROM 'Название программ'")
        program_names = [row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall()]

        connection.close()

        return program_names
    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        print("Ошибка при получении названий программ из базы данных:", e)
        return []

def create_fields(self, tab, tab_name):
    try:
        connection = sqlite3.connect('first.db')
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        # Создаем виджет Treeview для данной вкладки
        tree = ttk.Treeview(tab, columns=("Name", "Query"), show="headings")
        tree.heading("#1", text="Название")
        tree.heading("#2", text="Запрос")

        # Устанавливаем ширину столбца "Query" таким образом, чтобы текст автоматически переносился на следующую строку
        tree.column("#2", anchor="w", stretch=True, width=300, minwidth=50)

        # Создаем вертикальную полосу прокрутки для текста в столбце "Query"
        vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(tab, orient="vertical", command=tree.yview)
        vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
        tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

        tree.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="nsew")

        # Автоматически подстраиваемся под содержимое по ширине
        tab.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Выбираем запросы в зависимости от имени вкладки
        cursor.execute(
            f"SELECT название, запрос FROM 'SQL хранение в бд' WHERE [Название программы] = ?", (tab_name,))
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        print(f"Количество строк после выполнения запроса для вкладки {tab_name}: {len(rows)}")
        if rows:
            for name, query in rows:
                # Заменяем все разрывы строк на пробелы в тексте запроса
                query = query.replace('\n', ' ')
                tree.insert("", "end", values=(name, query))

        connection.close()
    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        print("Ошибка при работе с базой данных:", e)

def show_about_window(self):
    about_window = tk.Toplevel(self)
    about_window.title("О приложении")
    about_window.geometry("300x100")

    label_version = ttk.Label(about_window, text="Beta 1.0")
    label_version.pack(pady=5)

    label_developed_by = ttk.Label(about_window, text="Разработано в Белтаможсервис")
    label_developed_by.pack(pady=5)

def open_execute_window(self):
    # Создаем новое окно для выполнения запросов
    execute_window = tk.Toplevel(self)
    execute_window.title("Выполнение запросов")

    # Получаем размеры экрана
    screen_width = execute_window.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = execute_window.winfo_screenheight()

    # Вычисляем координаты для размещения окна по центру
    x = (screen_width - 800) // 2  # 800 - ширина окна
    y = (screen_height - 600) // 2  # 600 - высота окна

    # Устанавливаем координаты окна
    execute_window.geometry(f"800x600+{x}+{y}")

    # Создаем виджеты для отображения баз данных и их связей с программами и запросами
    label_databases = ttk.Label(execute_window, text="Выберите базы данных:")
    label_databases.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")

    # Получаем названия баз данных из таблицы "БД"
    database_names = self.get_database_names()

    # Создаем чекбоксы для каждой базы данных
    self.selected_databases = []
    for i, db_name in enumerate(database_names):
        var = tk.BooleanVar()
        checkbox = ttk.Checkbutton(execute_window, text=db_name, variable=var)
        checkbox.grid(row=i + 1, column=0, padx=5, pady=2, sticky="w")
        self.selected_databases.append((var, db_name))

    # Создаем выпадающий список для выбора программ
    label_program = ttk.Label(execute_window, text="Выберите программу:")
    label_program.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")

    program_names = self.get_program_names()
    self.selected_program = tk.StringVar()
    combo_program = ttk.Combobox(execute_window, values=program_names, textvariable=self.selected_program,
                                 state="readonly")
    combo_program.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

    # Создаем выпадающий список для выбора SQL-запросов
    label_query = ttk.Label(execute_window, text="Выберите SQL-запрос:")
    label_query.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")

    self.selected_query = tk.StringVar()
    combo_query = ttk.Combobox(execute_window, textvariable=self.selected_query, state="readonly")
    combo_query.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

    # Привязываем обновление списка запросов к изменению выбранной программы
    def update_queries(event):
        selected_program = self.selected_program.get()
        if selected_program:
            query_names = self.get_query_names(selected_program)
            combo_query["values"] = query_names
            combo_query.current(0)  # Устанавливаем первый элемент по умолчанию
        else:
            combo_query["values"] = []

    combo_program.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", update_queries)



    # Создаем кнопку "Выполнить" для выполнения выбранного запроса
    button_execute = ttk.Button(execute_window, text="Выполнить", command=self.execute_query)

    button_execute.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2, pady=10)

def get_database_names(self):
    try:
        connection = sqlite3.connect('first.db')
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT Название FROM 'БД'")
        database_names = [row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall()]
        connection.close()
        return database_names
    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        print("Ошибка при получении названий баз данных из базы данных:", e)
        return []

def execute_query(self):
    try:
        # Получаем выбранные базы данных
        selected_databases = [db_name for var, db_name in self.selected_databases if var.get()]

        if not selected_databases:
            messagebox.showerror("Ошибка", "Выберите хотя бы одну базу данных для выполнения запроса.")
            return

        # Получаем информацию о базах данных (названия и пути)
        database_names = self.get_database_names()
        database_paths = self.get_database_paths()

        # Получаем выбранный запрос и выполняем его для каждой выбранной базы данных
        selected_program = self.selected_program.get()
        selected_query = self.selected_query.get()

        print(f"Выполняемый SQL-запрос: {selected_query}")  # Отладочный вывод должен быть здесь

        for db_name in selected_databases:
            try:
                # Проверяем, есть ли выбранная база данных в списке доступных
                if db_name not in database_names:
                    messagebox.showerror("Ошибка", f"База данных '{db_name}' не найдена.")
                    continue

                # Получаем путь к выбранной базе данных
                db_path = database_paths.get(db_name)

                print(f"Путь к базе данных '{db_name}': {db_path}")

                # Подключаемся к базе данных SQLite
                connection = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
                cursor = connection.cursor()

                # Выполняем запрос
                cursor.execute(selected_query)

                # Получаем результаты запроса
                results = cursor.fetchall()

                # Выводим результаты в консоль
                print(f"Результаты выполнения запроса для базы данных '{db_name}': {results}")

                # Закрываем соединение
                connection.close()

            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Ошибка при выполнении запроса в базе данных {db_name}: {e}")

    except Exception as e:
        messagebox.showerror("Ошибка", f"Произошла ошибка при выполнении запроса: {str(e)}")

def get_query_names(self, program_name):
    try:
        connection = sqlite3.connect('first.db')
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(
            "SELECT название FROM 'SQL хранение в бд' WHERE [Название программы] = ?", (program_name,))
        query_names = [row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall()]
        connection.close()
        return query_names
    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        print("Ошибка при получении названий запросов из базы данных:", e)
        return []

def get_database_paths(self):
    try:
        connection = sqlite3.connect('first.db')
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT Путь FROM 'БД'")
        database_paths = {row[0]: row[1] for row in cursor.fetchall()}
        connection.close()
        return database_paths
    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        print("Ошибка при получении путей к базам данных из базы данных:", e)
        return {}
```

A lot of checks to understand which part of the code is not working